# async/await deadlock without using Task.Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a web api that is using async/await all the way down:

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentModel>> GetAll()
    {
        List<DocumentModel> modelItems = new List<DocumentModel>();

        var response = await SearchDocumentsAsync();
        var items = response.Results.ToList();
        foreach(var document in documents)
        {
            var model = new DocumentModel()
            {
                Id = document.Id,
                Name = document.Name
            };

            modelItems.Add(model);
        }

        return modelItems;
    }

    private Task<DocumentSearchResponse<Document>> SearchDocumentsAsync()
    {
        using (var searchClient = new SearchServiceClient(new SearchCredentials(searchServiceKey), searchServiceUri))
        using (var indexClient = searchClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName))
        {
            var parameters = new SearchParameters()
            {
                IncludeTotalResultCount = true
            };

            // call the Azure Search service
            return indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<Document>(search.Term, parameters);
        }
    }    
}
```

I am not using `.Wait()` or `.Result` anywhere in the call stack. Is it still possible for code like this to deadlock? When I debug this code I seem to be experiencing one but for the life of me I can't figure out why.

I have used Postman to send a couple of requests and sometimes the response never comes back. If I press the pause button in the debugger it will show a line in green that says "This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function." It is not consistent where the code will be when I press the pause button, but it seems that every other request will be blocked once one of them gets blocked.

Can the code above deadlock?

Comment: When you debug the code, where does execution stop?  You also need to provide a complete example that can replicate the problem for us to be able to provide a solution.

Comment: That said, deadlocks can be caused by lots of things, synchronously blocking the synchronization context while an asynchronous operation is trying to post a continuation to it is just one way to cause one.  There are plenty of others.

Comment: I mentioned that it's not consistent where it stops. I'm more interested in the code above. Is there anything being done in the code above that would cause a deadlock?

Comment: You've showed basically no code; there's no way to say if there's a problem with it or not.

Comment: @Servy I updated the code. I'm using the Azure Search REST api. I make a call to the REST API using the .net library and await the call...then I build a model with a few get/set properties that were returned from the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `SearchDocumentsAsync`, you're immediately returning the task from `SearchAsync`.

You should be awaiting this task to ensure `indexClient` and `searchClient` aren't disposed before the operation is complete. These being disposed may be what is introducing a deadlock.

Comment: If I change the code to add async / await in the SearchDocumentsAsync method instead of returning the task, but I remove the using statements and Dispose them in the ApiController.Dispose method will I run into any similar issues?

Comment: @Dismissile I don't know MVC well enough, could multiple threads call the same instance of `SearchDocumentsAsync` at once? If so you could run in to problems there. But if only one thread ever accesses the instance at once you should be fine to move the creation to the constructor and the dispose to the `Dispose()` of the class. Note: If you have methods that don't need the client created you could be introducing a unnecessary overhead on the other calls.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain each request in mvc would have its own instance so it's not really possible